# Access Hidden API

Tags: java, android, hardware

In class:

```
\\\android 1.5 source\frameworks\base\services\java\com\android\server\HardwareService
```

I have found method that looks like would help me in solving my Screen 
Brightness problems (smooth transitions):

**public void pulseBreathingLight()**

how to invoke this mysterious method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From an SDK application, you don't invoke "this mysterious method". It is not available in the SDK.

If you are creating your own device or are otherwise modifying Android firmware, it should be possible to access it -- just use [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch) to find places which call it and see how they use it.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the method to enable the trackball on the HTC devices to 'breathe'; smoothly light up and down like on Mac's. The same behavior when you receive a SMS.

Therefore, maybe not the API you're looking for...